# LUA using lua_newuserdata from lua_pcall

Tags: c, linux, lua

I fail to properly call a lua routine from C while setting an opaque handle before lua_pcall. (note: *Environment: Linux/OpenSuse42.2 with LUA-5.3 and GCC-5*)

The sequence I'm looking for.

- Start from C (not from LUA). In C create opaque handle (lua_newuserdata + luaL_setmetatable)
- set routine to call lua_getglobal(luaState, func);
- call lua func from C with lua_pcall (in my script Adjust_Volume_Speed)
- call back C from LUA (in my script  AFB_sucess). Note: the call works and LUA receive correctly arguments
- Back in C
- I can get my lua routine arguments but not my opaque handle
  Fail (luaL_checktype(luaState,1, LUA_TUSERDATA);

You can check my LUA code here after. When calling AFB_sucess from LUA I cannot retreive my userdata.

It seems that:

- if I push user_data before my  lua_getglobal(luaState, lua_func_name); then user_data is not used.
- If I push user data after the lua_getglobal then call to my lua routine fail with a message that complain that I try to call a user_data.

Question: when using lua_pcall, how to implement user_data in such a way that I may retrieve my opaque handle when LUA will reach a callback that happen to be implemented in C ?

The key lines involved in this are.

**Routine used to create/retrieve the opaque handle**

```
STATIC LuaAfbContextT *LuaCtxCheck (lua_State *luaState, int index) {
  LuaAfbContextT *afbContext;
  luaL_checktype(luaState, index, LUA_TUSERDATA);
  afbContext = (LuaAfbContextT *)luaL_checkudata(luaState, index, CTX_TOKEN);
  if (afbContext == NULL && afbContext->ctxMagic != CTX_MAGIC) {
      luaL_error(luaState, "Fail to retrieve user data context=%s", CTX_TOKEN);
      AFB_ERROR ("afbContextCheck error retrieving afbContext");
      return NULL;
  }
  return afbContext;
}

STATIC LuaAfbContextT *LuaCtxPush (lua_State *luaState, afb_req request, const char* info) {
  LuaAfbContextT *afbContext = (LuaAfbContextT *)lua_newuserdata(luaState, sizeof(LuaAfbContextT));
  if (!afbContext) {
      AFB_ERROR ("LuaCtxPush fail to allocate user data context");
      return NULL;
  }
  luaL_setmetatable(luaState, CTX_TOKEN);
  afbContext->ctxMagic=CTX_MAGIC;
  afbContext->info=strdup(info);
  afbContext->request= request;
  return afbContext;
}
```

**The Creation of LUA routine from C uses**

```
 // Push AFB client context on the stack
        LuaAfbContextT *afbContext= LuaCtxPush(luaState, request, func);
        if (!afbContext) goto OnErrorExit;

        // load function (should exist in CONTROL_PATH_LUA
        lua_getglobal(luaState, func);

        // push arguments on the stack
        if (json_object_get_type(args) != json_type_array) { 
            count= LuaPushArgument (args);
        } else {
            for (int idx=0; idx<json_object_array_length(args); idx++)  {
                count += LuaPushArgument (json_object_array_get_idx(args, idx));
                if (err) break;
            }
        }
```

**The routine to call LUA from C**

```
 static const luaL_Reg afbFunction[] = {
    {"notice" , LuaPrintNotice},
    {"warning", LuaPrintWarning},
    {"service", LuaAfbService},
    {"success", LuaAfbSuccess},
    {"fail"   , LuaAfbFail},
    {NULL, NULL}  /* sentinel */
};

// Create Binding Event at Init
PUBLIC int LuaLibInit () {
    int err, index;

    // search for default policy config file
    json_object *luaScriptPathJ = ScanForConfig(CONTROL_PATH_LUA , "onload", "lua");

    // open a new LUA interpretor
    luaState = luaL_newstate();
    if (!luaState)  {
        AFB_ERROR ("LUA_INIT: Fail to open lua interpretor");
        goto OnErrorExit;
    }

    // load auxiliary libraries
    luaL_openlibs(luaState);

    // redirect print to AFB_NOTICE    
    luaL_newlib(luaState, afbFunction);
    lua_setglobal(luaState, "AFB");


// Push AFB client context on the stack
        LuaAfbContextT *afbContext= LuaCtxPush(luaState, request, func);
        if (!afbContext) goto OnErrorExit;

        // load function (should exist in CONTROL_PATH_LUA
        lua_getglobal(luaState, func);

        // push arguments on the stack
        if (json_object_get_type(args) != json_type_array) { 
            count= LuaPushArgument (args);
        } else {
            for (int idx=0; idx<json_object_array_length(args); idx++)  {
                count += LuaPushArgument (json_object_array_get_idx(args, idx));
                if (err) break;
            }
        }
```

My LUA script

```
-- Adjust Volume function of vehicle speed
function Adjust_Volume_Speed (speed_meters_second)

  AFB:notice("In Adjust_Volume_Speed")

   print (string.format("***** Adjust_Volume_Speed speed=%d count=%d", speed_meters_second, count));

   -- compute volume
   volume = speed_meters_second * 2
   count=count+1

  AFB:success (1234, volume, count, 5678) 
end
```

Comment: >If I push user data after the lua_getglobal then call to my lua routine fail with a message that complain that I try to call a user_data. <br>You must put the function first, and arguments afterwards. If you get that error, that means the arguments given to lua_pcall() is incorrect. Probably you didn't pass correct number of Lua function's arguments on Lua stack.

Comment: I also found out that you need to push argument after lua_getglobal. What surprise me is that many example on the web do the opposite??? I found a solution passing a extra argument with lua_pushlightuserdata. If is not really what I wanted because the handle is visible from LUA script but at least it works :) My code is available here https://github.com/iotbzh/audio-bindings/blob/fulup-dev/Controler-afb/ctl-lua.c